# name of repository being appended to URL

Tags: jfrog-cli

Im trying to upload a file to my repo using the following command in JFrog CLI:

`jfrog rt u ".\Builds\mybuild.apk" buildrepo-generic-local --url=https://buildrepo-generic-local.artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/buildrepo-generic-local/Gitlab/mybuild/client/Test --user=myuser --password=mypass --build-name BuildName --build-number=0000`

but it appends the name of the repo on the url so it actually gets uploaded to:

`https://buildrepo-generic-local.artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/buildrepo-generic-local/Gitlab/mybuild/client/Test/buildrepo-generic-local/mybuild.apk`

and not where i want it which is:

`https://buildrepo-generic-local.artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/buildrepo-generic-local/Gitlab/mybuild/client/Test/mybuild.apk`

Im new so its probably me doing something wrong, anyone help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument of the upload command is the destination path in Artifactory. In your case that is:

`buildrepo-generic-local/Gitlab/mybuild/client/Test/mybuild.apk`

The url flag is the url of your Artifactory without path:

`--url=https://buildrepo-generic-local.artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/`

For more details, see the JFrog CLI [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-UploadingFiles).